# TextBox keypress (enter) increments datagridview selected row

Tags: c#, datagridview, textbox

I have  a textbox. when pressing enter, I want it to change the `DatagridView` selected row to the next row.

What I have so far below doesnt work.

```
private void textBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (int)Keys.Enter)
    {
        save_Click(sender, e);
        asd(sender, e);
    }
}


private void asd(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    SendKeys.Send("{Tab}"); //also tried enter
}
```

Comment: _doesnt work_ is a really useless and bad description. you ought to state just what does and what doesn't work. which parts of the code do get reached?? also: what is save_Click? And: sending a tab while the focus is in the textbox, will of course never work.. the guy with the illegible name has got good advice in his answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Should probably write the **Code** as follows to Iterate the row on **Key Down** Event of the **Text Box**!

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            int CurrentRow = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            CurrentRow++;
            if (CurrentRow < dataGridView1.Rows.Count)
            {
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[CurrentRow].Cells[0];
            }
            else
            {
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: in debug mode, this doesnt get called if i press enter on the textbox. http://imgur.com/0sP4baK thats what my app looks like. what i want to do is, enter a price, press enter, *DGV moves to next row*, enter price, repeat. im saving values and and stuff behind the scene but thats the general idea

Comment: Well in that case, All You Need to do is to write these lines in the **TextBox Key Down** Event!

Comment: this works almost perfectly, except pressing enter causes it to jump 2 lines rather than 1. any ideas?

Comment: nvm, i moved CurrentRow++ down to the end of the statement after else and it works now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The catch the enter key it is best to override `ProcessCmdKey`.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
    {
        if (yourTextBox.Focused)  // only when your are in the TextBox
        {
           advanceRow(yourDataGridView);
           return false;          // probably don't add new line
        }
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

To advance the currrent row best use a function..

```
int advanceRow(DataGridView dgv)
{
    int current = dgv.CurrentRow.Index;
    if (current < dgv.Rows.Count - 1)  // only if we hae not reached the bottom
    {
        dgv.CurrentCell = dgv[ 0, current + 1];
        return current + 1;
    }
    return current;
}
```